# Best values for an RC low-pass filter

Tags: filter, low-pass

I have a sonic sensor which outputs analog voltage in 0-10V range with some noise on it. The sensor will measure the distance changes so I'm interested in an output signal not more than 40Hz. The analog output will go to a DAQ which has more than 1Mega-Ohm impedance. Here is the data sheet of the sensor: http://files.pepperl-fuchs.com/selector_files/navi/productInfo/edb/104092_eng.pdf

I noticed that the high frequency sonic burst noise is interfering with the analog output. So I can filter it by an RC filter easily.

But my question is if I want to set the cut-off frequency to lets say 40Hz, there are many combinations for R and C. What should I consider when choosing R and C in this case?

Comment: You'd have to give us the sensor's impedance. A passive RC filter cannot be tuned to a fixed frequency without a known and constant source impedance.

Comment: I'm not trying to tune it to a specific freq. I'm just not interested in more than 40hz.  I added the data sheet http://files.pepperl-fuchs.com/selector_files/navi/productInfo/edb/104092_eng.pdf Is it written sensor's impedance here?

Comment: Okay. I don't have time to create a full answer right now, but 40 Hz *is* the frequency you intend to tune to. The datasheet states `≥ 1000 Ohm` as recommended load. Your DAC is way above that, so you're on the safe side. Your formula is `f = 1/(2*pi*RC)` with `f = 40 Hz`. Start with choosing a standard C value in the nF range (that you find affordable, quality supply for). Then calculate the R and the resulting impedance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) from there. Keep the filter impedance well above `1000 Ohm` and you should be good. ;)

Comment: Look at the datasheet under "Output."  You will find an entry for "load impedance."  Your RC-Filter must present an impedance of at least 1kOhm to the sensor.  So, use a 2kOhm as the R, and calculate a C that gets the cutoff down to 40Hz.  Alternatively, pick a C and try values until you get an R above 1kOhm for 40Hz.  You want R above the output impedance of the sensor but way below input impedance of the ADC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load impedance specified in the product data sheet must not be less than 1 kohm when using the 0 to 10V output. The input impedance of your DAQ is (say) 1 Mohm so go for something that is about logarithmically halfway at \$\sqrt{1k\cdot1M}\$ = ~33k ohm.

However, you might want to check what leakage currents are produced by the DAQ's inputs to see that 33k does not create an offset error that is too large. I don't expect it will. You might want to consider how much error 33k series resistance produces when there is a 1M ohm to ground after it (about 3.3%). If this is too much choosing 10k will give an error of about 1%.

Comment: Im currently using 1uF and 3.9k. Would that be very ok?

Comment: Yeah that's fine.

Comment: I was wondering what would be the advantage or dis advantage of using higher R and nF level cap.  They gave same cut off but still

Comment: Higher R gives higher DC error due to input impedance of DAQ. How much error can you live with (as explained in my answer).